# How to improve the security on a ASP.NET site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET site and some clients want a better layer of security for accessing it. The site today asks for a username and password, but a lot of clients want to restrict the access to some machines and I need to do this on my server side. So, I'm asking for some advice.

1. Use a VPN to restrict the access? (With mobile devices will not work)
2. Is possible to check the mac address?
3. Is possible to use client certificate?

Comment: Could you use a two step authentication method. User/Pass gets you to the next screen where you have to enter a verification PIN, Image Match, Txt Code ect.

Comment: Do they want to restrict access to certain machines or just make it more secure?  A second factor will make it more secure; maybe something like Authy?  https://www.authy.com/ (also available as smartphone app, so portable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Easiest for the User

I would examine [multi-factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) (to which Andrew Walters' comment alludes) with all content delivered over SSL and extra care taken around things like page timeout, session fixation, password policies, etc.

A PIN delivered to a cell phone is a commonly used second factor.

I assert that this is "easiest for the user" because so many large sites (e.g. Google and Facebook, their bank) operate in this fashion. There's nothing to install and nothing new to learn.

This many not be desirable from a business perspective.

### VPN

> Use a VPN to restrict the access? (With mobile devices will not work)

This is a common option in corporate environments and is typically considered secure (although not an excuse for abandoning other good practices like password policies). However, you *do* have options for mobile devices.

See [F5's SSL VPNs](http://www.f5.com/it-management/solutions/ssl-vpn-security/overview/), specifically their [whitepaper on mobile access for iOS and Android](http://www.f5.com/pdf/white-papers/mobile-access-to-applications-tb.pdf) which states, *"The BIG-IP Edge Portal app for iOS and Android devices streamlines secure mobile  access to corporate web applications [...] users can access internal web pages and web applications securely."*

You can increase security by adding another factor into the authentication process: a [token with a continually changing PIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID).

### Certificates

> Is possible to use client certificate ?

Yes, it is [possible](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753983%28WS.10%29.aspx); whether or not it meets your business needs is a different matter (e.g. there is skill/time required in managing such a solution).

If you aren't familiar with the subject, I suggest reading this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=907274) (a quick read).

For implementation, here's an old but highly detailed [walkthrough](http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=11) and a newer [walkthrough](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/configuring-iis-7-with-self-signed-server-and-client-certifi) for IIS 7.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to lock down access to certain machines, use IIS's http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions.  Specify which IPs have access > make sure you set them to static in dhcp.  This is the "access on a need be basis approach" used by payroll vendors and credit card companies in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Use a VPN to restrict the access?**

Would definitely work. It does limit the machines you can work with.

**2) Is possible to check the mac address ?**

It is, but it's not a secure method as MAC addresses can be spoofed.

**3) Is possible to use client certificate ?**

That might be your best bet actually.